# how to sort a list based on a specific keywords in the string

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have this list below

```
my_list = ['STNNC-A11-SD03', 'STNNC-BDD-SD01', 'STNNC-BDD-SD04', 'STNNC-BDB-SD02']
```

i tried below method and this is what it returned which is expected since its sorting from left to right:

```
my_list.sort()
print(my_list)

['STNNC-A11-SD03', 'STNNC-BDB-SD02', 'STNNC-BDD-SD01', 'STNNC-BDD-SD04']
```

but below is the output i am looking for

```
['STNNC-BDD-SD01', 'STNNC-BDB-SD02', 'STNNC-A11-SD03', 'STNNC-BDD-SD04']
```

is there anyway that i can sort the list based the last numerical section?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to sort based on the third component of each string, you can use:

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda s: s.split("-")[2])
```

This produces:

```
['STNNC-BDD-SD01', 'STNNC-BDB-SD02', 'STNNC-A11-SD03', 'STNNC-BDD-SD04']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted()` and extrcat the number from string use the number as key in `sorted`

```
res = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: int(x.split('-SD')[-1]))
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['STNNC-BDD-SD01', 'STNNC-BDB-SD02', 'STNNC-A11-SD03', 'STNNC-BDD-SD04']
```

Answer (score -2):

#you can try this, I hope you will get you solution.

```py
my_list = ['STNNC-A11-SD03', 'STNNC-BDD-SD01', 'STNNC-BDD-SD04', 'STNNC-BDB-SD02']

base_list = []
for i in my_list:
    base_list.append(int(i[-2:]))

zipped_lists = zip(base_list, my_list)

sorted_zipped_lists = sorted(zipped_lists)

sorted_list = [element for _, element in sorted_zipped_lists]

print(sorted_list)
```

Comment: Please explain the code. Avoid source code only answers.